# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Intel graphics driver not working with nomodeset in grub

Tags: 16.04, drivers, grub2, intel-graphics, nomodeset

I am currently trying to set up a system with a Intel Atom CPU (Braswell). I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on it. Display is a small touch display and in order to get the right screen format, so fullscreen, I need to add in **/etc/default/grub** the option **nomodeset**.

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"

Afterwards "sudo update-grub"

However, when I add this line in grub, "Details" (the desktop package) shows me as "Graphics" instead of "**Intel HD Graphics 400(Braswell)**" this driver here: "**llvmpipe (LLVM 6.0, 128 bits)**" and the command **xvinfo** tells me

```
X-Video Extension version 2.2
screen #0
no adaptors present
```

By default (no nomodeset!) the Ubuntu installation shows me 1 adaptor called **Adaptor #0: "GLAMOR Textured Video"**

If I install the packages **xorg-xserver-video-intel** and **xorg** and reboot I get the adaptors **Adaptor #0: "Intel(R) Textured Video** and **Adaptor #1: "Intel(R) Video Sprite"** listed (if I don't have nomodeset in grub) and output from a camera works really good and smoothly. These are also the same adaptors as on my workstation.

However with these packages installed and the entry of **nomodeset** in **/etc/default/grub** I end up with a blackscreen while booting (hangs at **Starting Show Plymouth Boot Screen**).

So it seems like I can choose between right display format and right graphics drivers. While searching for this problem I mainly found problems with nvidia drivers and nomodeset fixed that issue. However here it seems like it's the other way round.

Does anyone know how to get the intel graphics drivers running while still using nomodeset in grub? Or how I can change the displays resolution without nomodeset (wanted resolution not available in "Displays" package (GUI))?  I would appreciate every help I can get.

Comment: `nomodeset` disables all drivers. It is not a permanent option to be used. It is needed to boot safe without any driver. Changing screen resolution is done a different way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I thought `nomodeset` only instructs the kernel to not load video drivers and use BIOS modes instead until X is loaded. So I thought after the login screen is loaded it has no impact on drivers again.